# arangodb custom JsonDeserializer for document

Tags: java, jackson, arangodb, json-deserialization

I'm trying to set custom deserializer for object which I get from arangodb.

MyDocument is class which I store in arangodb:

```
public class MyDocument {

     private MyContent content;
     ...

     public MyContent getContent() {
       return content;
     }

     public setContent(MyContent content) {
       this.content = content;
     }
}
```

MyContent is an interface for which I want to have custom deserializer:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = MyContentDeserializer.class)
public interface MyContent {
    ...
}
```

MyContentDeserializer looks like this:

```
 public class MyContentDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<MyContent> {
 @Override
     public DocumentContent deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        ...
     }
 }
```

When I try to get MyDocument from database with

```
 arangoDriver.getDocument("myDocument", key, MyDocument.class)
```

MyContentDeserializer.deserialize method isn't execute, instead I got exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface MyContent. Register an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.
at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$12.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:210)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:186)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:103)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:196)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:810)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:875)
at com.google.gson.Gson$1.deserialize(Gson.java:128)
at com.arangodb.entity.EntityDeserializers$DocumentEntityDeserializer.deserialize(EntityDeserializers.java:753)
at com.arangodb.entity.EntityDeserializers$DocumentEntityDeserializer.deserialize(EntityDeserializers.java:728)
at com.google.gson.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:58)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:810)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:775)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:724)
at com.arangodb.entity.EntityFactory.createEntity(EntityFactory.java:162)
at com.arangodb.BaseArangoDriver.createEntityImpl(BaseArangoDriver.java:367)
at com.arangodb.BaseArangoDriver.createEntityWithFallback(BaseArangoDriver.java:259)
at com.arangodb.BaseArangoDriver.createEntity(BaseArangoDriver.java:236)
at com.arangodb.BaseArangoDriver.createEntity(BaseArangoDriver.java:311)
at com.arangodb.impl.InternalDocumentDriverImpl.getDocument(InternalDocumentDriverImpl.java:262)
at com.arangodb.ArangoDriver.getDocument(ArangoDriver.java:1908)
at com.arangodb.ArangoDriver.getDocument(ArangoDriver.java:1893)
```

Comment: Did the answer work for you? if yes, can you mark it 'accepted'? If not, whats missing?

Comment: Done, sorry for delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@JsonDeserialize` is `Jackson` annotation and your stacktrace tells us that you use `Gson` for deserialization. So you have to register `Gson` deserializer or use `Jackson`

Comment: Yes, that's clear, but how to turn on Jackson in arangodb ? Is it possible at all ?

Comment: @pieniak if you use `arangodb-java-driver`, then from this issue: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb-java-driver/issues/15 **we have no plans add support for Jackson**